# Multi Tenancy Sign Up option is not available in WSO2 API Manager Store

Tags: wso2, store, multi-tenant

With respect to WSo2 API Manager Store, I have 2 tenants created in Management Console.

I am able to view those tenants in Store but expect carbon tenant, other users doesnt have an option Signup.

I tried this link too but its not working. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Customizing+the+API+Store

Can anyone guide me please?

Comment: Can you please recheck whether you have followed documentation correctly. You have to login to management console using tenant admin permissions and then follow these steps.

Answer (score 1):

By default, self sign up is disabled for tenants AFAIK. You can enable this by following the below steps.

1. Login to management console as tenant admin
2. Go to the registry browser which can be found in the left menu.
3. Traverse to /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/sign-up-config.xml file.
4. Change  to true.

After that, go to the api store and you should see the sign up button.